# Como Acceder a un valor concreto y borrarlo o modificarlo SesionStorage

Tags: javascript, dom

Buenas estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con JSON, local y sesion  Storage, mi problema es que tengo un Json creado y al intentar acceder a un valor no consigo modificarlo o borrarlo, se que con sessionStorage.clear() y sessionStorage.removeItem(clave) puedo borrar todas las key o una en concreto pero quiero borrar un único valor o modificarlo y no lo consigo. a ver si podéis ayudarme!!!

```js
 sessionStorage.setItem(`clientes: 1`, JSON.stringify({
      "nombre": "Yann Poirot",
    "edad": 30,
    "userName": "Yann",
    "password": "4321",
    "emails": "yaan@gmail.com",
    "foto": "",
    "peliculas": [
      {
        titulo: "Never Rarely Sometimes Always",
        fecha: "21/03/2019",
        horario: "10:30",
        nEntradas: "3",
        butacas: [{

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        }],
        sala: "1",
      },

      {
        titulo: "La dolce vita",
        fecha: "23/01/2021",
        horario: "19:00",
        nEntradas: "2",
        butacas: [{

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        }],
        sala: "3",
      },
    ],


    }))
```

Este seria el JSON que he almacenado a sesion Storage y ahora quisiera acceder a el para modificar el parámetro Películas. hay que tener en cuenta que cada vez que salgo de la pestaña y vuelvo a acceder con esta función no hago nada por que al pintar el historial de películas en el DOM se vuelven a cargar de ahi que quiera borrarlos solo a ellos del historial con un botón que ya esta creado

```
var user2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('clientes: 0'));

//BORRAR HISTORIAL
 function borrarHistorial(){
 user2.peliculas = user2.peliculas('');
// document.getElementById('historial1').innerHTML = 'Tu historial está vacío'
console.log('borrado')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diría que tienes unos tres fallos, uno tipográfico y otro de asignación y uno de omisión.

- El tipográfico es porque aquí estás asignando el `clientes: 0`:

```
var user2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('clientes: 0'));
```

cuando en el objeto que has puesto en la pregunta es `clientes: 1`, por lo tanto deberia ser así:

```
var user2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('clientes: 1'));
```

- Y el segundo es la asignación que haces siguiente:

```
user2.peliculas = user2.peliculas('');
```

que da error de javascript. Cuando lo que quieres es hacer esto para resetearlo:

```
user2.peliculas = [];
```

- Y el de omisión es que luego no vuelves a almacenar ese objeto modificado en la variable de sessionStorage, que deberias hacer así al final de la función borrarHistorial():

```
sessionStorage.setItem(`clientes: 1`, JSON.stringify(user2))
```

Dejo un snippet con todo a la vez (y como aquí no te funcionará puedes probarlo en [este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/8hsw13bm/)):

```js
sessionStorage.setItem(`clientes: 1`, JSON.stringify({
  "nombre": "Yann Poirot",
  "edad": 30,
  "userName": "Yann",
  "password": "4321",
  "emails": "yaan@gmail.com",
  "foto": "",
  "peliculas": [{
      titulo: "Never Rarely Sometimes Always",
      fecha: "21/03/2019",
      horario: "10:30",
      nEntradas: "3",
      butacas: [{

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        }
      ],
      sala: "1",
    },

    {
      titulo: "La dolce vita",
      fecha: "23/01/2021",
      horario: "19:00",
      nEntradas: "2",
      butacas: [{

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        },
        {

        }
      ],
      sala: "3",
    },
  ],


}))
var user2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('clientes: 1'));
borrarHistorial()
//BORRAR HISTORIAL
function borrarHistorial() {
  user2.peliculas = [];
  console.log('borrado')
  sessionStorage.setItem(`clientes: 1`, JSON.stringify(user2))
}
console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(`clientes: 1`)))
```

Comment: Gracias!!! tienes toda la razón será el cansancio últimamente estoy unas 11 o 12 horas seguidas con el ordenador estudiando y se me pasan cosas, has sido muy amable por tu respuesta, pero sobre todo por tu explicación !!!!